# How to Pull changes done on the aws appsync console to my local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have made changes to my AppSync project on the AppSync web console and I want to pull it onto my local machine.

I have seen the [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625341/how-can-i-pull-changes-made-on-the-appsync-web-console-with-the-amplify-cli-pul)  but there is no proper solution for this issue can anyone help me figure this out.

Comment: Hi Mohamed and welcome to Stackoverflow! You should have a quick read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which may help you in getting the answer you need. Provide as much detail as you can and where possible, provide visual queues some others can help diagnose your issue.

Comment: You should not change cloud resources directly, amplify builds ( if you are using amplify) cloud stack itself and manages using cloudformation. If you add/update/delete any resource you might end up with broken amplify project. I ll discourage anyone manually updating cloud resource. Make respective changes on your local machine and run `amplify push`

Comment: @sakhunzai can you please tell me, is there any way to tell amplify to fetch the updated appsync changes? I am new to AWS, and I think there should be a way to use cloudformation to update the amplify's knowledge to fetch updated changes.